# css override reason

Tags: html, css

why does row 2 "Test 2" get overridden with orange?

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        td
        {
            color: white;
        }
        .testclass td
        {
            background-color: Orange;
        }
    </style>
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr class="testclass">
                <td style="background-color: Blue">
                    Test 1
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="testclass">
                <td bgcolor="fushcia">
                    Test 2
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`bgcolor` is a presentational HTML attribute. It will always be overridden by any actual CSS style declarations.

This is mentioned in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#preshint):

> The UA may choose to honor presentational attributes in an HTML source document. If so, these attributes are translated to the corresponding CSS rules with specificity equal to 0, and are treated as if they were inserted at the start of the author style sheet.

In plain English, this means presentational attributes have almost no meaning, and are even more brittle than styles in a `*` rule in an author stylesheet (which also has zero [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity)).

Comment: "In particular, a selector of the form "[id=p33]" is counted as an attribute selector (a=0, b=0, c=1, d=0), even if the id attribute is defined as an "ID" in the source document's DTD." Huh, interesting.

Comment: @JAB: Yup :) Whether an attribute is considered an identifier is defined by the document language, not CSS. Plus, not every language considers `id` an identifier (e.g. XML uses `xml:id` instead). And since you can't infer any of this information from looking at a stylesheet alone, CSS parsers can't just assume `id` represents an identifier either. So, an attribute selector is treated as just that: an attribute selector.

Comment: So with XML, the selector `#apple` would be referring to an XML element with `xml:id="apple"`?

Answer (score 1):

Bgcolor is deprecated since HTML 4.01 and as such you shouldn't use it, try background: or background-color:

Answer (score 1):

CSS styles have priority over HTML markup, I believe.